# Not able to install SONAR

Tags: sonarqube

I am new user of Sonar.

I have a small project in java which i want to analyse with Ant.

I am trying Installed Sonal 2.13

I execute 
bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat

I have Java 1.6

It gives me Error

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:09 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:09 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/02/06 10:48:10 | Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7    \lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:10 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:14 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2012/02/06 10:48:14 | Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:14 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:18 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2012/02/06 10:48:18 | Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:18 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:23 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2012/02/06 10:48:23 | Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:23 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 | Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/02/06 10:48:27 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I didnt understand this. i am using java 1.6   ; jre 6

how to solve this Problem

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, it looks like the version of Java in your PATH is Java 7, not Java 6.
secondly, maybe you're not running on a Windows 64-bits, but a 32-bits, so you should try running the StartSonar.bat script inside the "windows-x86-32" folder instead if this is the case.

Comment: SonarSource : Windows is 64 bits. When i type 
      javac -version 
in command promt , it shows me 
      javac 1.6.0_27

Comment: Fabrice appears to be on the right track. The error message is listing a Java 7 path: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg"

Comment: @NewCodeLearner: you should not type "javac -version" but "java -version" (for which you will certainly get "1.7").